# node listen to a shell executable output

Tags: json, node.js, sockets

I have this small task where I have an executable file that I run and it gives me a flow of json lines.

I want a node script that could listen to that executable and handle the output.

The executable I simply run through the teminal with:

```
./generator
```

after I do this, it will start running and display json files until I manually stop it.

Comment: take a look at child_process in the node libs https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options - you should be able to add a listener to "data" from the stdout of the child process and JSON.parse whatever comes out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var content = '';

var child = spawn('./generator');
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  content += data;
});

child.on('close', function() {
  console.log(content);
});
```

Here is a working code which you can run to spawn the generator script as a child and receive all of its standard output.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please add some context around your code?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the package [ndjson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ndjson). You will pipe your child process's stdout into `ndjson.parse()`, which will return a readable stream. You will listen for the `data` events on that readable stream and get objects already parsed for you. (The example in the ndjson README is directly applicable to your situation).